# Integrate $\int\frac{\cos^5(x)}{\sin(x)^{1/2}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I can't find a way to solve this:
$$\int\frac{\cos^5(x)}{\sin(x)^{1/2}}dx$$
I'm not sure how I have to proceed, can you help me? I've tried the substitution $u=\sin x$, but it got me nowhere.

Comment: Have you tried the [Weierstrass substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution#The_substitution)?

Comment: Is sin(x)^1/2: $\sin(x^{1/2})$ or $\sqrt{\sin(x)}$?

Comment: it is  sin(x)−−−−−√

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*}
\int \frac{\cos^5 x}{\sin^{1/2} x} \,dx
&= \int \frac{(1-u^2)^2}{\sqrt u} \,du &&\text{($u=\sin x$)} \\
&= \int 2(1-v^4)^2 \,dv &&\text{($v = \sqrt u$)}
\end{align*}
Now it's just a polynomial; expand the square, integrate term by term, and replace $v$ with the equivalent in $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$
\frac{\cos^5(x)}{\sin(x)^{1/2}} = \frac{\cos(x)(1-\sin(x)^2)^2}{\sin(x)^{1/2}}.
$$
Now use the substitution $u=\sin x$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

**(Long) METHOD 1:** See that
$$\dfrac{d\sqrt{\sin x}}{dx}=\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{\sin x}}\cos x\\
\implies \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\sin x}}\cos xdx=2d\sqrt{\sin x}$$
Thus,
$$\int\dfrac{\cos^5x}{\sqrt{\sin x}}dx=2\int{\cos^4x}d\sqrt{\sin x}=\\
2\left(\sqrt{\sin x}\cos^4x+4\int\sqrt{\sin x}\cos^3 x\sin xdx\right)$$
Now, $\int\cos^3 x\sin^{3/2} xdx$ can be calculated by $\dfrac{d\sin^{5/2}x}{dx}=\dfrac{5}{2}\sin^{3/2}x\cos x$, i.e., $\sin^{3/2}x\cos xdx=\dfrac{2}{5}d\sin^{5/2}x$. Continue integration by parts.

**(Shorter) METHOD 2:** Use the identity $1-\sin^2 =\cos^2$, to get
$$\int\dfrac{(1-\sin^2x)^2}{\sqrt{\sin x}}dx=2\int2{(1-u^4)^2}du,\text{ $u=\sqrt{\sin x}$}\\
\implies \int\dfrac{(1-\sin^2x)^2}{\sqrt{\sin x}}dx=\int(1+u^8-2u^4)du=\\
\boxed{\sqrt{\sin x}+\dfrac{\sqrt{\sin^9 x}}{9}-2\dfrac{\sqrt{\sin^5x}}{5}+C}$$